# Как сделать красивую пунктирную рамку с закруглениями?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css3

Всем привет. Я сделал drag n drop input, и хочу, чтобы он был красивый) Но, мне не очень нравиться, что у моей пунктирной рамки с закруглениями немного, как будто, обрезаются края или что-то подобное. В общем, есть ли какой-нибудь вариант сделать это получше, чтобы в самих краях так же был отрезок с закруглениями? Делаю я, если что, на React + mui.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Перфекционизм - зло. Не трать время. Многие не обращают внимание на такие мелочи.

Comment: Но ведь хочется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попросите дизайнера создать штрихпунктирный путь `path` в svg квадратной формы, нужного размера и закругления, потом добавьте эту рамку через `background` к диву оббертки этой обрасти. Через CSS такого не получить, простыми способами.

Comment: Эх, я так и думал, что просто не будет) Спасибо, что пояснили)

Answer (score 0):

Не?

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 5px dashed #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div>ee</div>
```

Comment: Ну, да, тут намного лучше. Но, у меня радиус закругления меньше, т.к. стандартный в mui меньше. А если оставлять такой большой, то немного странно выглядит

Comment: @ДимаЭф Подкрутите `border-radius: 20px;`, сделайте как нравится.